# Excel 2013 - Creating 2-data series chart with column width is dynamic (depend on variable)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-office-2013

Using Office 2013 suite (Excel 2013), how to I create x/y graph, we additional dependencies where X columns widths dependant on additional value?

For example, from values such as:

```
    Height  Width
A   100       5
B   90        4
C   80        5
D   100       3
F   50        5
```

To have a chart that looks like:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Comment: Read the tutorial you lifted the first image from (http://peltiertech.com/variable-width-column-charts/).

Comment: @JonPeltier I have read it, it uses another version of Excel that got different UI and eventually suggesting me to download chart plugin. I understand that it's yours site, and you did a great job, but it's not what i need...

Comment: The only thing that's really different is where you change the horizontal axis type. In 2013 it's called a Date Axis, not Time-Scale Axis, and instead of being buried in Chart > Options, it's right on the Format Axis dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

[image]

Here are the formulas I used to get there.

In D2 enter the following, then copy to cells D3:D7:

```
=SUM($C$1:C1)+1
```

In E2 enter the following, then copy to cells E3:E7:

```
=IF(A2="",NA(),A2)
```

In G2 enter the following, then copy down as far as you like (I copied down to row 24)

```
=IF(ISTEXT(G1),0+1,G1+1)
```

In H2 enter the following, then copy down as far as you like (I copied down to row 24)

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,$D$2:$E$7,2,TRUE)
```

In I2 enter the following, then copy down as far as you like (I copied down to row 24)

```
=IF(H2=H1,"",H2)
```

In J1 enter the following as an array formula (by pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` instead of just `Enter`, then copy across as far as you like (I copied over to column N)

```
=TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$6)
```

In J2 enter the following, then copy down and over as far as you like (I copied down to cell N35)

```
=IF(J$1=$H2,VLOOKUP(J$1,$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE),NA())
```

When you set up your chart, the data for the columns is in columns J:N. And the labels are in column I.

To hide for data that isn't there, just hide the data (like I've hidden rows 24:35)

Then it's just formatting.